# How to ignore routes from specific dlls in Sitecore 8.2

Tags: routing

Sitecore 8.2 update 1.

I have added few dll refences in project. The DLLs are from external application and have their own webapi controllers and routes.

I am using Autofac and excluding the assemblies from external application on startup (for **builder.RegisterControllers**)

When I navigate Experience Analytics dashboard, it errors out. The logs have a message that the route name "xxx" (external dll route) is already added to route collection and must be unique. But I do not see any other issue with the site. It looks like when I am navigating to Experience Analytics, it is trying to load the routes again.

When I remove the dlls from bin, there are no more errors in Experience Analytics.

I have added the names of the dll to be excluded in **Sitecore.Mvc.config** file section  `excludedAssemblies`. Also I have added the same dlls to `Sitecore.Services.Client.Config`  excluded assemblies section for `Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.Pipelines.ServicesWebApiInitializer, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore`

When I add the following:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(
    new ExcludeByControllerNameRouteProvider( "external dll name"));
```

to **Global.asax**, it throws an error

> A route named '**MS_attributerouteWebApi**' is already in the route
>   collection.

So i reverted it.

1. Why is Sitecore still adding routes from external dlls to the route dictionary?
2. How do I exclude certain dll routes.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the exception from Logs when i navigate to the experience analytics dashboard

```
Exception 
System.ArgumentException: A route named 'CartLinesV1' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique.
Parameter name: name
   at System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.Add(String name, RouteBase item)
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.AddGenerationHooksForSubRoutes(HttpRouteCollection routeTable, IEnumerable`1 entries)
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<MapAttributeRoutes>b__0(HttpConfiguration config)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.ApplyControllerSettings(HttpControllerSettings settings, HttpConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.InvokeAttributesOnControllerType(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type type)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.InvokeAttributesOnControllerType(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type type)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor..ctor(HttpConfiguration configuration, String controllerName, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.InitializeControllerInfoCache()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
16520 18:46:27 ERROR [Sitecore Services]: HTTP GET
URL http://preview.local/sitecore/api/ao/aggregates/all/786FBA3A4573445EA74504E3CA5E48C1/all?&dateGrouping=by-week&&dateFrom=19-10-2016&dateTo=19-01-2017&keyGrouping=collapsed
```

The code that I am using to exclude certain dlls from Autofac register is:

```
    var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    assemblies = assemblies.Where(x =>
            !x.FullName.StartsWith("ignore_dlls_name.")).ToArray();
    builder.RegisterControllers(assemblies);
```

I confirmed that it is not adding the external dlls to autofac ContainerBuilder.

Comment: please, provide:
1) Code that you use to exclude assemblies/routes
2) exception stacktrace from sitecore logs

Comment: added in the description.

Comment: can you check if you are using 
        `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` somewhere in your global.asax?

Comment: I added config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); in gloabl.asax.cs thats when i get "A route named 'MS_attributerouteWebApi' is already in the route collection." error. So i removed it.

Comment: A strange that the error is only when I view Experience Analytics and Experience Profile from Launchpad. Almost looks like its initializing all the routes again when i view Experience Analytics or Experience Profile.

Comment: Small question, but isn't `Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.Pipelines.ServicesWebApiInitializer` registering controllers and initializing routes?  I thought 8.2 handled that out of box and one would not need to have the DI container register those on startup.

Comment: Yes, there's an exclude assemblies configuration too that doesn't register controllers/routes from specified dlls